# I have text data, and want to get it into AWS

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have what is essentially a traditional relational database, consisting of four tables, all related with IDs. Currently this database resides in four tab-delimited text files, in an S3 bucket. Very little, if any, data will ever be added to these tables. It is an unchanging reference database. So it will be exclusively read from, never added to or edited.

I would like to access this database in an Alexa skill. I've built a few skills already, using NodeJS, so I know how that all works. But I'm anxious to learn how to link up a skill with a back-end DB. This skill will need to do SQL SELECT statements against this DB, based-on user-provided parameters, and based on the query filter be able to pull a set of records into an array that can be used by my skill's lambda function.

Each of the current text files holds one of four tables. The largest table is about 35k rows. Whole DB is maybe 5 Mb, 90% of which is one of the four. Like I said, they are all connected with ID columns like a traditional RDBMS. This will not be for commercial purposes. Probably.

I am already familiar with SQL Server, it's the DB I know, and I'm comfortable with SQL Server Express and can whip something up there, but I'm open to learning NoSQL or some other method if it's more appropriate for this use case. And as this is mostly a learning exercise, if something is "just as good", it's good for me to know.

What is my best DB solution? 
* NoSQL such as DynamoDB?
* Some sort of MySQL?
* SQL Server?
* Leave them as tab-delimited text and use them from the Lambda function directly?

Thanks, I don't want to start down the wrong road here.

Answer (score 0):

A few options...

**S3 Select**

[S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) (in Preview at the time of writing this) "enables applications to retrieve only a subset of data from an object by using simple SQL expressions. By using S3 Select to retrieve only the data needed by your application, you can achieve drastic performance increases – in many cases you can get as much as a 400% improvement."

**DynamoDB**

The benefit of using DynamoDB is that there is no need to run a database server -- it is a fully-managed service. While it doesn't support SQL syntax, it is very fast and can suit many use-cases.

In fact, most projects should consider using a NoSQL database like DynamoDB for every situation, unless there is a particular reason to use SQL (such as business reporting).

Cost is based upon storage and provisioned capacity (which can scale-up and down based on demand).

**SQL Database**

Yes, you can certainly run an SQL database, either through Amazon RDS (Relational Database Service) or on your own EC2 instance (eg MySQL or even [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/). However, you are then paying for the server even when it isn't being used.

Using Microsoft SQL Server is probably too much for your use-case (and more expensive than using an open-source product).

I wonder if you could incorporate [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) in your app, which would provide SQL capabilities without much overhead?

**Do it in memory**

5 MB is, quite frankly, not much data. You could simply load all the data into memory and do your manipulations from there. While the load might consume a few cycles, data access will be very quick after that.